# Azure API Management - 500 Internal Server Errors

Tags: azure-api-management, http-status-code-500

Following the best practices we've created a similar infrastructure, based this [architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/apis/protect-apis).

Recently we've imported several external API (those APIs are exposed on public IPs) so they can be used in our organization. Those APIs are working, but randomly we get intermittent 500 Internal error messages.

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xx.xx.xx.xx:443.
> Usually it takes between 20-45 seconds to display this error.

There are some articles on how to troubleshoot this kind of behavior, but in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/troubleshoot-response-timeout-and-errors) from MS, they suggest to move the backend in the same virtual network, which is not possible, because it's not our API.

Have any of you experienced the same behavior? If so, how did you manage to troubleshoot it?

We've set up a new API Management that is not connected to an internal network and tried to reproduce this behavior, but all requests returned 200 OK, therefore I'm excluding a problem with the backends.

We've tried a retry policy, but it's a bad/frustrating experience for the end client and not always successful.

Comment: is it exactly failing at 21 or 42 seconds?

Comment: @MohamadHaidar yes, most of them fail at around 21 and 42 seconds

Comment: That is TCP handshake failure either due to SNAT port exhaustion which you can check from your azure portal by going to your service -> Diagnose and solve problems -> Availability and Performance -> SNAT Port Analysis. Or it could be a device between your APIM service and the backend rejecting the handshake due to some reason, one of these reasons is that APIM keeps the idle connection alive for 4 mins and drops the connection after that, if the backend or a device in the backend keeps the connection alive for more than that, then that would cause TCP handshake failure.

Comment: @MohamadHaidar I've checked the SNAT Port Analysis report tab but there were no errors displayed there, even if I can find all the errors in the logs.
I've also checked the Backend 5xx Responses report tab - there is no error displayed there as well.
I've set the time range to the last 1 hour for a clearer view, but I see only successful operations.

Comment: if there is no SNAT port exhaustion then there should be a device between your apim service and your backend (or the backend itself) causing this issue.

Comment: APIM uses sticky connections and keep and idle connection alive for maximum 4 min, if there is a network device (like a firewall) between your APIM and your backend that keeps those connections at its end alive for more than 4 mins, the next TCP handshake by APIM that uses the same source Port and IP of the connection that has been dropped will fail as that network device thinks that it still has a socket open using that source port and IP as APIM silently drops those connections without sending a reset packet to your backend

Answer (score 0):

In the reference [architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/apis/protect-apis), an **Application Gateway** is used.

By default, the Application Gateway has a "*Request time-out*" on the backend settings of 20 seconds. This could be the issue when running long request to the APIM.

For more information on backend timeouts of an Application Gateway, look at [Backend server timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#backend-server-timeout) and [Request time-out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502#request-time-out).

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation of intermittent 500 errors returned by APIM to API client. After consulting Microsoft support, we decided to implement their recommendation and use an automatic retry mechanism applicable on all APIs:

```
<backend>
    <retry condition="@((context.Response.StatusCode == 500) || (context.LastError?.Reason == "BackendConnectionFailure"))" count="5" interval="2" first-fast-retry="true">
        <forward-request buffer-request-body="true" />
    </retry>
</backend>
```

Comment: We've tried that as a workaround with 3 retries, but if you get multiple consecutive errors, it gets annoying for the end user. Imagine that you get a response in normal operation in 1-2 seconds max; suddenly you wait for 20 seconds (it fails), the APIM will run the retry policy (it fails again and wait another 20 seconds). For the end user it's a very bad experience.